# I am unable to understand the execution of following c code

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define sqr(a) a*a

int main()
{
    int i;

    printf("%d",64/sqr(4));

    return 0;
}
```

Why am I getting the output as 64 .

Normally what should happen is it first checks the value for `sqr(4)` and then divide . In case of any other operator it works fine .

Please Explain .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After preprocessing the printf line will be:

```
printf("%d",64/4*4);
```

which should explain why it prints 64.

Always use parenthesis in macros definitions when they contain expressions:

```
#define sqr(a) ((a)*(a))
```

Even this is not safe against macro invocations like:  `sqr(x++)`. So don't use marcos unless you have to :)

Answer (score 0):

Macros aren't functions, they're (mostly) dumb text replacement. Your macro lacks parentheses, so when the preprocesor replaces it, you'd get the following:

```
printf("%d",64/4*4);
```

Since `/` and `*` have the same precedence, this is like stating `(64/4)*4`, which is, of course, `64`.

If you want your `sqr` macro to safely square its argument, wrap it in parentheses:

```
#define sqr(a) (a*a)
```

Answer (score 0):

`64/sqr(4)` is expanded to `64/4*4`.

You have to parenthetise the macro body and should also put parenthesis aroud the argument:

```
#define sqr(a) ((a)*(a))
```

Yields:`64/(4*4)`

Note that macros are pure *textual* replacements performed by the *C preprocessor* **before** the actual compilation starts.

A better and type-safe approach would be to use an `inline` function:

```
static inline int sqr(int a)
{
    return a * a;
}
```

This will likely be *inlined* into the caller code by the compiler as much as the macro would be. OTOH, the compiler might very well decide not to, depending on internal heuristics. In general, you should trust the compiler to use the proper way, unless you have serious performance/code-size issues.

This will also protect against evaluating the argument `a` twice. That is critical if there are side-effects like

```
int i[2], *p = i;
sqr(*p++);
```

For the macro version, this will result in undefined behaviour (undefined order of evaluation):

```
((*p++) * (*p++))
```